# Make 2 divs appear on different delays

Tags: javascript, html, delay

I'm trying to make one div appear after a delay, and another div appear after another delay. Both codes work alone, but not together. I changed all the variables so why isn't this working? I understand you might be able to fix this a different way, but I want it to be in this format. Thanks

```
<script>
//appear after 1 second
window.onload = function(){

  var theDelay = 1;
  var timer = setTimeout("showText()",theDelay*1000)
}
function showText(){
  document.getElementById("delayedText").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
<div id="delayedText" style="visibility:hidden">
 1st Text
</div>


<script>
//appear after 2 seconds
window.onload = function(){

  var theDelay2 = 2;
  var timer2 = setTimeout("showText2()",theDelay2*1000)
}
function showText2(){
  document.getElementById("delayedText2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
<div id="delayedText2" style="visibility:hidden">
 Appear 2nd
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are cancelling out the first window.onload by defining it again. Do it in one.

```
<div id="delayedText" style="visibility:hidden">1st Text</div>
<div id="delayedText2" style="visibility:hidden">Appear 2nd</div>    

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var theDelay = 1;
    var timer = setTimeout("showText()",theDelay*1000)
    var theDelay2 = 2;
    var timer2 = setTimeout("showText2()",theDelay2*1000)
}

function showText(){
    document.getElementById("delayedText").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function showText2(){
    document.getElementById("delayedText2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5DgQS/

Or if you need to add the window.onload events separately you can do so without overwriting each time. I would use a function to control this. e.g.

```
// create the function to add a window.onload event

if (typeof addLoadEvent!='function' ){
    function addLoadEvent(func){    
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){
            window.onload = func;
        }else{
            window.onload = function(){
                oldonload();
                func();
            }
        }
    }
}


// reuse it as many times as you want

addLoadEvent(function(){

  var theDelay = 1;
  var timer = setTimeout("showText()",theDelay*1000)

});

addLoadEvent(function(){

  var theDelay2 = 2;
  var timer2 = setTimeout("showText2()",theDelay2*1000)

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5DgQS/1/